How do I make the keyboard and trackpad work on Macbook 12 early 2015 hardware
In previous versions of Ubuntu when I would try the live USB stick / installer on the Macbook 8,1 early 2015 the keyboard and trackpad never worked.  This time when I tried Ubuntu 24.04 the keyboard and trackpad worked in the live environment.  After installing and restarting into 24.04 the keyboard, trackpad, and it seemed like the wifi all didn't work.  Since it is working in the live environment it must be possible to make it work in the local install without having to install kernal mods from GitHub repos (other posted suggestions), right?  I would like to solve this with Ubuntu in repo options so that I don't have to do manual kernel work every time there is an update.  Anyone have any ideas on what is running in the live environment that I could install/turn on for the install?
